# JSP, "User cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am working through Murach's Java Servlets and JSPs
I am in chapter 4, when I load http:// button is pressed I get the error.  Can anyone see what is causing the problem, I have all the files stored in tomcat/webapps/MailList.  I have gone through this code for hours and cannot find any syntax causing the problem, just thinking another set of eyes would probably catch it.  Or someone could explain it, any help is greatly appreciated, this is my first day messing with Servlets/JSPs and tomcat.

The **join_email_list.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chapter 4 - Email List application</title>
    </head>
    <body background="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Lighthouse.jpg" >
        <h1>Join the Murach's mailing list</h1>
        <p>To join the Murach's mailing list, enter your name and email address below.<br>
            Then, click n the submit to recieve special offers.</p>
        <form action="show_email_entry.jsp" method="get">
            <table cellspacing="5">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" >First name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="firstName"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Last name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastName"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">email address</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="emailAddress"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the **show_email_list.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html public"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chapter 4 - Email List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%@page import="business.*, data.*" %>
        <%
            String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
            String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
            String emailAddress = request.getParameter("emailAddress");
            User user = new User(firstName, lastName, emailAddress);
            UserIO.addRecord(user, "..webapps/MailingList/UserEmail.txt");
        %>
        <h1>Thanks for joining</h1>
        <table cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
                <td align="right">First Name: </td>
                <td><%= user.getFirstName() %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Last Name: </td>
                <td><%= user.getLastName() %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Email Address: </td>
                <td><%= user.getEmailAddress() %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <form action="join_email_list.html" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Return">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the **User.java** class

```
package business;

public class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailAddress;
    //this class defines a user, what we can get from a user to store
    public User(){}
    public User(String first, String last, String email){
        firstName=first;
        lastName=last;
        emailAddress=email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

}
```

the **UserIO.java** class

```
package data;

import business.User;
import java.io.*;

public class UserIO { //the user io class adds the entered info to a txt file a.k.a psuedo db
    public synchronized static void addRecord(User user, String fileName) 
            throws IOException{
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( //open the printwriter
                new FileWriter(fileName, true)); //write to file
        out.println(user.getEmailAddress()+"|"//write these things to file
                +user.getFirstName()+"|"
                +user.getLastName());
        out.close();//close out to free resources
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the class path of `User` class ?

Comment: C:\tomcat\webapps\subdirHTML\User.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
UserIO.addRecord(user, "MailingList/UserEmail.txt");
```

instead of

```
UserIO.addRecord(user, "..webapps/MailingList/UserEmail.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

`user` is not in not accessible in the scope you are trying to, also

```
C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Lighthouse.jpg
```

is not going to work

Comment: How could I access the User class then.  I got this from the book and am trying to learn, so I am not sure how else I could get the User class from the show_email_list.jsp